# How can I access to Vue.js application using IP

Tags: django, vue.js

I'm working on a small project using Vue.js / Django Rest Framework. Now I just want to visit my work, but I don't know which IP address I have to use in the browser to see my work, I tried everything.

This is my vue.config.js:

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
    publicPath: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
    outputDir: './dist/',

    chainWebpack: config => {

        config
            .plugin('BundleTracker')
            .use(BundleTracker, [{filename: './webpack-stats.json'}])

        config.output
            .filename('bundle.js')

        config.optimization
            .splitChunks(false)

        config.resolve.alias
            .set('__STATIC__', 'static')

        config.devServer
            // the first 3 lines of the following code have been added to the configuration
            .public('http://127.0.0.1:8080')    
            .host('127.0.0.1')    
            .port(8080)
            .hotOnly(true)
            .watchOptions({poll: 1000})
            .https(false)
            .disableHostCheck(true)
            .headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["\*"]})

    },

    // uncomment before executing 'npm run build' 
    // css: {
    //     extract: {
    //       filename: 'bundle.css',
    //       chunkFilename: 'bundle.css',
    //     },
    // }

     };
```

I do `npm run serve` and `python manage.py runserver` but when I try accessing in the browser nothing is working.

Comment: Vue CLI outputs the app's URL when you run `npm run serve`. Just open that URL.

Comment: "I tried everything", can you be a bit more specific? Does this mean you have tried `localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080` in the browser? What else have you tried?

Comment: This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.   @OscarSchafer

Comment: @OscarSchafer     terminal give me :    
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://127.0.0.1:8080/ 
  - Network: http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Comment: @AliceMunin It's worth pointing out that the port number (the 8080 on the end) is important. Just `127.0.0.1` will give you a "refused to connect" error, but `127.0.0.1:8080` should work. Secondly, make sure you're trying on the same machine as you're running the `npm run serve` command.